# Create Low Pass Filter by Octave

Tags: fft, octave, lowpass-filter

Though I had an example of low pass filter coded in Octave and I'm sure it works, I can't understand.
How dose this work? and How can I know cut-off frequency of this filter?

The original_data is a column of water quality data I obtained with 1Hz.

```
l = rows(original_data);
a = fft(original_data);
for i = (1:l);
 if i >9
  a(i) = 0;
 endif
endfor
b = fft(original_data);
for i = (1:l)
 if i > 1
  b(i) = 0;
 endif
endfor
c = real(ifft(a));
c(1);
d = real(ifft(a))*2-c(1);
```

If you have any idea, please help me.

Comment: This is a really bad way to do filtering - it's a brick wall in the frequency domain which means there will be severe ringing artefacts in the time domain. Use a window function in the frequency domain to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Do you know how to know cut-off frequency of this filter?

Comment: The cut-off frequency depends on the size of the fft, which appears to be `l`, so it would be approx `Fs * 10 / l`, and you say that `Fs = 1 Hz`, so that would be approx `10 / l` Hz.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment, there are plenty of functions to allow you to design a low-pass filter correctly (see http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/overview.html, in particular the IIR and FIR filter design sections). Once you have designed your filter you can apply it using the function `filter` or `filtfilt`.

As an example, a simple way to go about this would be:

```
[b,a] = butter(n, Wc) % low pass Butterworth filter with cutoff pi*Wc radians - choose the order of the filter n and cut-off frequency Wc to suit
filtered_data = filter(b,a,original_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly is important know that works in frequency domain is not the best way to filter a signal, time domain methods can work nicely !

Do you want know the cut-off frequency? you need know the sample rate and the length of your FFT to calculate the frequency of correspondent bin of your FFT.

sample rate = FS, first do you need calculate the Nyquist.

```
Nyquist = FS / 2;
```

Now find the frequency resolution, in this case your fft size is the same of your original_data.

```
Resolution=Nyquist / (length(original_data) / 2);
```

OK almost ther, you are placing the value 0 in the first eight(8) bins of your FFT, then now you need find the frequency of correspondent bin!

```
round(1 * Resolution)
round(2 * Resolution)
round(3 * Resolution)
.
.
round(8 * Resolution)
```

The results are the cut-off frequency, this means that you will be cutting the frequencies between the first and eighth bin